# The inverse function of a logarithm equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I've tried many things with this question, and just can't seem to get it quite right, can someone please show me how to answer this question? Thank you in advance.
$$g(x) = \ln(5x+25) \qquad g^{-1}(x) = \frac{\boxed{\phantom{X}}}{\boxed{\phantom{X}}} e^{x}\,\boxed{\phantom{XXX}}$$

Comment: Do you know how to take an inverse?  I would try letting g(x)=y, swap the variables x and y so you have $x=\ln(5y+25)$ and solve for y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the inverse, I would let $g(x)=y$, then solve for $x$ in terms of $y$. After that, I would swap $x$ and $y$, then replace $y$ with $g^{-1}(x)$. We have our function:
$$g(x)=\ln(5x+25)$$
First, rewrite with $\log_e$ instead of $\ln$.
$$g(x)=\log_e(5x+25)$$
Make the substitution $g(x)=y$.
$$y=\log_e(5x+25)$$
Remember that if $\log_a(b)=x$, then $a^x=b$.
$$e^y=5x+25$$
Solve for $x$
$$5x=e^y-25$$
$$x=\dfrac{e^y-25}{5}$$
Swap $x$ and $y$.
$$y=\dfrac{e^x-25}{5}$$
Change $y$ into $g^{-1}(x)$
$$g^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{e^x-25}{5}$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{g^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{5}-5}$$

Answer (score 1):

To find the inverse of the function $g(x) = \ln( 5x + 25) $, solve for $x$

$$ g = \ln( 5x + 25) \iff e^g = 5x + 25 \iff x = \frac{e^g - 25}{5}$$

$$ \therefore g^{-1}(x) = \frac{e^x - 25}{5} = \frac{1}{5} e^x - 5 $$

Comment: My question had 5x? Why did you change it?

Comment: I did not change it!

Comment: You had ***e^y + 25/5*** before, that made more sense.

Comment: and how do I put the answer in the form of the given placeholders on the right?

Comment: @SamirChahine That should be fairly simple... just use
$$\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac ac + \frac bc$$

Comment: @SamirChahine You're right. I fixed the error.